# How to fix the Stackoverflow in the following method?

Tags: java, recursion, exception, stack-overflow

I am trying to program a method that handles user Input. The method needs to scan from the console an int, check if scanned int was in Range and then check the validity of the data before scanning another int in another method. I decided to program the method recursively, that it will call itself to repeat if the mentioned conditions are not met.

```
 public static void readUserInputDay(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.print("Day (1-31): ");
        try {
            int tmp = scanner.nextInt();
            day = new Integer(tmp);
            
            if(isTheInputInRange(day.intValue(), DAY)) {
                readUserInputMonth(scanner);
            } else {
                System.out.print("Number isn't in Range (1-31)\n");
                readUserInputDay(scanner);
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a number!\n");
            readUserInputDay(scanner);
        }
    }
```

The other filters work as expected, however if I enter on the console something that is not an int the Exception is triggered and catched (As expected) but when I expect the Method to recursively repeat itself, I instead get the following output on the console:

```
Day (1-31): Please enter a number!
Day (1-31): Please enter a number!
Day (1-31): Please enter a number!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8.updatePositions(UTF_8.java:77)
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8.access$200(UTF_8.java:57)
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder.encodeArrayLoop(UTF_8.java:636)
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder.encodeLoop(UTF_8.java:691)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:579)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:271)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:129)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:526)
    at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:669)
    at MyClass.readUserInputDay(MyClass.java:27)
    at MyClass.readUserInputDay(MyClass.java:43)
    at MyClass.readUserInputDay(MyClass.java:43)
```

Do have any ideas how I need to fix the code, so when method call itself, it doesn't enter immediately in the catch block ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found the solution to my original problem by adding a scanner.next(); before calling the method recursively again the catch block. However I agree with @Mustafa Poya
 and Billy Brown that a while loop is the better solution

Answer (score 0):

you are calling the method inside of itself 3 times and according to conditions it cause to re-call it self and at the end `overflow error`.
to prevent from this problem at first try to change the structure of your code and use while loops for example to continue your code at a certain condition you want and get the result:

```
public static void readUserInputDay(Scanner scanner) {
    try {
        boolean isFinished = false;
        // your condition for loop
        while (!isFinished) {
            System.out.print("Day (1-31): ");
            int tmp = scanner.nextInt();
            day = new Integer(tmp);
            if (isTheInputInRange(day.intValue(), DAY)) {
                readUserInputMonth(scanner);
                isFinished = true;
            } else {
                System.out.print("Number isn't in Range (1-31)\n");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("Please enter a number!\n");
        readUserInputDay(scanner);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is the correct answer. With respect to author desire to use recursion here - this is a bad idea because there is a stack call limit and your program will break sooner or later in [any case](https://freecontent.manning.com/stack-safe-recursion-in-java/#:~:text=Default%20stack%20size%20varies%20between,case%20is%20recursive%20method%20calls.)

Answer (score 0):

It is odd that you say the StackOverflow error occurs on the first retry, especially within the first `System.out.print` call.

However, as Mustafa suggested, using a `while` loop rather than recursion is a much better choice in this case, as it will not cause new stack frames to be created every time somebody enters the wrong text (as I do not think that Java can do tail call optimisation on that method).

```java
public static void readUserInputDay(Scanner scanner) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Day (1-31): ");
        try {
            int tmp = scanner.nextInt();
            day = new Integer(tmp);
            
            if (isTheInputInRange(day.intValue(), DAY)) {
                readUserInputMonth(scanner);
                break; // exit the retry loop
            } else {
                System.out.print("Number isn't in Range (1-31)\n");
            }
      
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a number!\n");
        }
        // By this point, the input is invalid, so loop again
    }
}
```